# Stop setTimeout bootstrap modal on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I create modal using Bootstrap 4 and in backend I add settimeout to close the modal after X secounds.

But if the user didn't finish reading that modal, this is my main goal: I want to stop the settimeout once the mouse inside the modal & again if the mouse outside modal, settimeout again work to finish the event.

My code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        var myModal = $(this);
        clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));
        
        myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
            myModal.modal('hide');
        }, 3000));
    });
});
```

Comment: You can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343695/make-bootstrap-popover-appear-disappear-on-hover-instead-of-click

Comment: @AleKennedy thanks for your reply, but it's not what im looking for, sounds in the demos looks like tooltip, what im looking for include the modal once its open i want when mouse in side the settimeout STOP, than when mouse out again settimeout work to close the modal :) could you add the code to me 

Comment: @jonrsharpe u edit the answer after 5 years man ! u free till that's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monitor mouseover of modal-content

```
$(function(){
    $('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        var myModal = $(this);
        clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));

        $('.modal-content', myModal).on('mouseover', function() {
            clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));

        });

        $('.modal-content', myModal).on('mouseout', function() {
            myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
                myModal.modal('hide');
            }, 3000));

        });

        myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
            myModal.modal('hide');

        }, 3000));

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval to increment the time spent not minding the modal:

```js
let beforeClose;
let mouseIn=false;
const openModal = () => {
  document.querySelector('#modal').style.display='block';
  beforeClose = 100;
  let int = setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector('#countdown').innerHTML = beforeClose;
    if (!mouseIn) beforeClose--;
    if (beforeClose==0) {
      closeModal()
      clearInterval(int);
    }
  }, 1000/24);
}
const closeModal = () => document.querySelector('#modal').style.display='none';
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openModal()">Open modal</button>

<br>

<div id="modal" onmouseover="mouseIn=true" onmouseout="mouseIn=false">
  <p>
    Closing the modal at 0 : <span id="countdown"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Hover me to pause the countdown
  </p>
</div>
```

(I used a div instead of a modal, but under the hood it's the same)

Comment: i swear what you did is exactly what im looking for, but i try to add what you showed me but didn't work & there's issue after the countdown finish and modal close try to click one more time, the time will start again with ( -0 , -1 , -2 etc.. ) check here my code http://jsfiddle.net/dbawtgfh/

Comment: Edited m answer to correct the bug. Please upvote and accept if that answer is fine!