# Add popover when mouse-up event triggered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am going to draw rectangle over image on html canvas. And I want to show popover with form just after mouse-up event of rectangle. Can Anyone suggest option to do this?
Below I added what I have tried, and it was not succeed.

```js
$("h2 > .editable").popover({
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="popover">
  <span class="editable" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-title="Edit" data-content="<form>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='annotation'>label</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='lbl'  placeholder='Enter name'/>
  </div>
 
  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
</form>">
                    </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: And how about you share with us witch popover plugin you are using, as popover is not not standard jquery...

Comment: @ikiK I am using popper.js (src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js)

Comment: HI, where is mouseup event ?

Comment: @Swati That's what I am stuck. Could you please elaborate how to configure popover with mouse-up event

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343695/make-bootstrap-popover-appear-disappear-on-hover-instead-of-click) post might be helpful.

Comment: @Swati It is related to this. Thank you for the support!